# libspotify Python package for calling Spotify api?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, spotify

I'm building an app that needs to get artwork information out of the libspotify Spotify API.

I'm building the app in python on google appengine. Does anyone know of a package that will enable me to access the libspotify API? The [official page is C](http://developer.spotify.com/en/libspotify/overview/) and I've googled around to try and find a suitable wrapper but can't seem to find one.

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 3):

There is also https://github.com/mopidy/pyspotify which is actively used in some applications and up to date.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you will be able to call libspotify at all. From the [docs](https://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/overview.html):

"The Python interpreter runs in a secured "sandbox" environment to isolate your application for service and security. The interpreter can run any Python code, including Python modules you include with your application, as well as the Python standard library. The interpreter cannot load Python modules with C code; it is a "pure" Python environment."

Comment: I realise I can't access the full controls to play/pause etc but all I want to do here is look up artwork for an album given a spotify URL. Feels like that might be possible?

Comment: Unfortunately the appengine is not able to determine you intentions, it only detects that you are trying to "reach" outside the sandbox (which it wont allow).

Answer (score 0):

Check Spotimeta

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/spotimeta/

Comment: Thanks, but that only queries the metadata API which doesn't include the artwork. I need full libspotify access for the artwork.

Comment: As far as I know you will not be able to get artwork information directly using this api.